Blank UI after adding a child fragment to FragmentContainerView
I genuinely need help with an issue that I have been stuck with for some time. I joined my company a couple of months ago. Since migrating the Android app, I have been facing many challenges along the way (mostly due to coding that needs to be replaced or updated).
One of those issues that I encountered recently, is the use of FragmentContainerView. The project was very messy in the past, and the objective now is to streamline and improve it's performance. And that begins here.
I have one MainActivity for my project. This is the starting Activity. And then I would have another Fragment that will be added to the Activity's FragmentContainerView. And then within that first child fragment, I will have a tab layout which will then add another child fragment.
This is inside the main activity:
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mxb_fragment_container" />

When the main activity loads up the first time, inside the onCreate(), I will have a function that would add the home screen called initHomeFragment(). This one has no issues. I'm just sharing this for more context to the problem that I am facing.
When I try to add in the next fragment (triggered by a button that is tapped), a very interesting thing happened (after repeated observations):

(Debug mode) When I run the app in debugging mode, the subsequent child fragment (the fragment with the child view) will load up.

(Normal mode) When I stop debugging and run the app in the normal "Run" mode, the child fragment would not load up anymore. I just get a blank screen. I even tried to create a function to call at the end of the loading of the tab-related fragment. The FragmentContainerView will show that there are 2 children. Which is correct since there is the Home and Favourites fragments now added to the container.


private void switchFragmentView(Fragment pShowFragment, Fragment pHideFragment, Bundle args, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setReorderingAllowed(true);
    if (pHideFragment != null) {
        ft.hide(pHideFragment);
    }
        
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        if (pShowFragment instanceof MxFavouritesFragment)
            ft.add(R.id.mxb_fragment_container, MxFavouritesFragment.class, args, tag);
    } else {
        ft.show(pShowFragment);
    }
        
    ft.commit();
}

Inside the MxFavouritesFragment...
getChildFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.mxb_fav_main_container, RecentFavouritesFragment.class, null, RecentFavouritesFragment.LOG_TAG)
    .commit();

Inside MxFavouritesFragment, I am using a FrameLayout instead of the FragmentContainerView. I have tried using the same container view here, but it didn't work as well.
What can I do to ensure that the UIs are loaded up properly and there isn't a blank screen?
I have followed some online tips to use the invalidate() or requestLayout() functions, which should force the container to redraw itself. But for some reason, it doesn't appear to be doing anything (from what I could tell).
